# Not sure how to handle multi touch

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a simple game where the player draws shapes on the screen. The points of the path is stored in an array and drawn in the class GameLoop. I'm almost done, but now I realize that I should have done the game with multi touch input to allow two player to draw shapes at the same time!

I know that I need to use `event.Action_Down` for the first finger and `event.Action_Pointer_Down` for the next finger, but how do I handle the points of all shapes and the drawing of the path? Can I still just use one array, or do I need an array for each. It feels that I'm needing to double all code in my GameLoop class to check both path? My question might be a little bit unclear, but that how I feel right now! Some advice would be nice!

This is the code how I handle single touch events and pass all points to an array:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    synchronized (gameLoop) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            gameLoop.touchDownX = event.getX();
            gameLoop.touchDownY = event.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = (int) event.getX();
            point.y = (int) event.getY();
            gameLoop.addPoints(point);
            gameLoop.startDrawLine = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Point point2 = new Point();
            point2.x = (int) gameLoop.touchDownX;
            point2.y = (int) gameLoop.touchDownY;
            gameLoop.addPoints(point2); // Add last point to close shape
            gameLoop.pathOK = true;
            gameLoop.touchActionUp = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

EDIT:
This was complicated! I found some code that I have modified a little. I need to create an arrayList for each person that starts drawing a shape on the screen. There must be possible for several players to draw shapes at the same time. All Point values should be stored inside the `player` arrayList. Finally all `player`arrayList should be stored inside a main arrayList called `players`. Can I get some help to solve this? I don't know how to start.

I have declared my lists in the GameLoop class:

```
        // Lists to handle multiple touch input
    players = new ArrayList<List<Point>>(); // Main arrayList
    player = new ArrayList<Point>(); // Inner arrayList
```

The code below is in the MainActivity class and I use an object of `GameLoop` like `gameLoop` to communicate with the GameLoop methods.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    synchronized (gameLoop) {

    for(int i=0; i<event.getPointerCount(); i++) { // Numbers of pointers on screen

        int id = event.getPointerId(i);

        // Check if fingers touch screen
        if (event.getActionIndex() == i && (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )) {


        }

        // Check if fingers leave the screen
        else if (event.getActionIndex() == i && (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {


        }

        // Check movement on screen
        else {

        }   
    }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, that handles the motion history of all pointers at once:

```
void printSamples(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
    final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();
    for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
        System.out.printf("At time %d:", ev.getHistoricalEventTime(h));
        for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
            System.out.printf("  pointer %d: (%f,%f)",
            ev.getPointerId(p), ev.getHistoricalX(p, h), ev.getHistoricalY(p, h));
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("At time %d:", ev.getEventTime());
    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
        System.out.printf("  pointer %d: (%f,%f)",
        ev.getPointerId(p), ev.getX(p), ev.getY(p));
    }
}
```

You will have to create several arrays for several pointers. You can use a `HashMap<Integer, List<Point>>` to map from pointer ID to list of `Point`s for that pointer.

Here's the guide for `MotionEvent` with the example I posted above:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Edit: Tried to match the code to your needs:

```
private HashMap<Integer, List<Point>> myPoints;

private void addPoints(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
    final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();
    for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
            addPoint(ev.getPointerId(p), new Point(ev.getHistoricalX(p, h), ev.getHistoricalY(p, h)));
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("At time %d:", ev.getEventTime());
    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
        addPoint(ev.getPointerId(p), new Point(ev.getHistoricalX(p, h), ev.getHistoricalY(p, h)));
    }
}

private void addPoint(Integer pointerId, Point point) {
    List<Point> points = myPointers.get(pointerId);

    if (points == null) {
        points = new LinkedList<Point>();
        myPointers.put(pointerId, points);
    }

    myPointers.get(pointerId).add(point);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Seems very complicated :( I will take a closer look later

Comment: Not that complicated. You have a history of the motion locations, of size `getHistorySize()` and in each history entry, you have `getPointerCount()` pointers. Then you can see the location of each pointer in a given history event by using `getHistoricalX(pointer, history)`. All you have to do then, is put the correct event in the correct list, per pointer, and that's what the `HashMap` is for.

Comment: Hi again! I'm trying to understand your code example. Can I use arrayLists instead of hashMaps?

Comment: The idea of the hashmap, is that you have 2 lists, one per cursor (ie one per finger that touches the screen). You can use 2 linked lists, but then the maximum multi touch will be 2, and you will have to do an `if (p == 0) linkedlist1... else linkedlist2...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what if I need more than 2 user that touches the screen? The reason why I'm asking for arrayLists is because I already had used arrayLists from the beginning. My thought was to have a main arrayList to hold several arrayLists, one for each finger!?

Comment: If there can be more than 2 I recommend using the hashmap. Notice that inside the hashmap there is a list (you can use arraylist). This means, that calling the hashmap.get(touch_id) will return an arraylist and you can use your old code!

Comment: Don't I also need to use code like ev.getActionMasked() and MotionEvent.Action_Down and MotionEvent.Action_Pointer_Down and others?

Comment: the addPoints method does the mapping of the motion event into the array lists. When to call it depends on your program logic (for example, in your `onTouch()`, probably when the type is `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`).